# Can I set a Word document to automatically enable macros when it's opened and autosave it to a server?

Tags: ms-word

I have a web application in which I upload my Word document that contains a macro. When this document is downloaded and opened, I want the macro to be enabled because most of my users don't have macros enabled. Is it possible for me to enable a macro while the document is opened? Or is there another way of implementing automatic saving of the document to the server on close?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for your macro to magically enable macros if the user has chosen not to enable them. That's the point of macro security. The user has the control, not your code. What would be the point of the user disabling macros if your macro could just reenable them?

I don't know what you mean by your second question.

Comment: The second question means that I am downloading a word document from a web site and make changes to the document Now once i save the document and am closing the samei want it to be updated at the server too !

Comment: Now you're getting outside of my area, and things that Word all by itself can do.